# How to speed up GLM estimation?

Tags: performance, r, bigdata

I am using RStudio 0.97.320 (R 2.15.3) on Amazon EC2. My data frame has 200k rows and 12 columns.

I am trying to fit a logistic regression with approximately 1500 parameters.

R is using 7% CPU and has 60+GB memory and is still taking a very long time.

Here is the code:

```
glm.1.2 <- glm(formula = Y ~ factor(X1) * log(X2) * (X3 + X4 * (X5 + I(X5^2)) * (X8 + I(X8^2)) + ((X6 + I(X6^2)) * factor(X7))), 
  family = binomial(logit), data = df[1:150000,])
```

Any suggestions to speed this up by a significant amount?

Comment: I don't have an immediate suggestion on speed but as far as inference goes you should not be using `var+I(var^2)`. Instead you should use `poly(var,2)`. You have constructed an incredibly complex formula and it is not at all clear that you need such a monster. You should describe the research question and get further advice about analysis design, and you should probably do so over at CrossValidated.

Comment: I doubt that fitting 1500 parameters will give a useful result.

Comment: Interesting technical question, although I agree with the other commenters' concerns.  (1) There is a `fastLm` function in the `RcppArmadillo` package that illustrates how to speed up linear regression http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/fast-linear-model-with-armadillo/ , but re-implementing GLM would be more work. (2) Installing an optimized BLAS library might be lower-hanging fruit: http://www.r-bloggers.com/faster-r-through-better-blas/ . (3) Linear regression might work OK, although N/P is only 133 in this case. (4) Try penalized GLM via the `glmnet` package ...

Comment: (5) since some of your predictors are factors, you might buy some speed by using a sparse model matrix (see `?glm.fit` and `?sparse.model.matrix` in the `Matrix` package) -- especially if your factors have many levels.

Comment: Thanks Ben, factor(X1) has ~40 levels, Factor(x7) has 3. Is this sparse enough for the Matrix package?

Comment: You should seriously consider using `glmnet` it's really fast (it uses gradient descent) and with 1500 parameters to fit I don't think that regularization (through elasticnet) would hurt....

Comment: glmnet looks interesting dickoa, but I am having trouble making my variables+formula into a matrix which glmnet can use, any advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple packages to speed up `glm` fitting. [fastglm](https://github.com/jaredhuling/fastglm) has benchmarks showing it to be even faster than `speedglm`.

You could also install a more performant BLAS library on your computer (as Ben Bolker suggests in comments), which will help any method.

Comment: can I use speedglm on stepwise?

Comment: Don't use stepwise. Use the lasso instead.

Answer (score 7):

Although a bit late but I can only encourage dickoa's suggestion to generate a sparse model matrix using the Matrix package and then feeding this to the speedglm.wfit function. That works great ;-) This way, I was able to run a logistic regression on a 1e6 x 3500 model matrix in less than 3 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your design matrix is not sparse, then you can also consider my package `parglm`. See [this vignette](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/boennecd/parglm/blob/master/vignettes/parglm.html) for a comparison of computation times and further details. I show a comparison here of computation times [on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53355070/5861244).

One of the methods in the `parglm` function works as the `bam` function in `mgcv`. The method is described in detail in

> Wood, S.N., Goude, Y. & Shaw S. (2015) Generalized additive models for large datasets. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series C 64(1): 139-155.

On advantage of the method is that one can implement it with non-concurrent QR implementation and still do the computation in parallel. Another advantage is a potentially lower memory footprint. This is used in `mgcv`'s `bam` function and could also be implemented here with a setup as in `speedglm`'s `shglm` function.

Comment: can you add a tiny bit more context about what `parglm` does (i.e. how it achieves computational effiiciency)?

Comment: I have done as in the `bam` function in `mgcv` by first estimating a series of QR decomposition on different chunks of the data. The results are then combined at the end. Further details can be found in "*Wood, S.N., Goude, Y. & Shaw S. (2015) Generalized additive models for large datasets. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series C 64(1): 139-155*".

Comment: That's great. Can you edit this explanation into your question (comments are ephemeral)?