# How can I use multi cores processing to run glm function faster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, logistic-regression

I'm a bit new to r and I would like to use a package that allows multi cores processing in order to run glm function faster.I wonder If there is a syntax that I can use for this matter.
Here is an example glm model that I wrote, can I add a parameter that will use multi cores ?

```
g<-glm(IsChurn~.,data=dat,family='binomial')
```

Thanks.

Comment: not easily. You may be able install a vectorized/multicore BLAS (linear algebra) library.  Perhaps take a look at Revolution R ...

Comment: e.g. http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2010/06/performance-benefits-of-multithreaded-r.html  (but see the comments there about whether this will actually help `glm`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284766/how-to-speed-up-glm-estimation-in-r

Comment: `glm` does not use the BLAS. I am not aware of any multicore glm implementation in open source R. Revolution (which you have to pay for) has a faster implementation of glm.

Comment: @JamesKing there are some level 1 BLAS calls e.g., [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/appl/dqrdc2.f#L163-L164). Though, it is only level 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used speedglm and the results are very good: using glm it took me 14.5 seconds to get results and with speedglm it took me 1.5 sec. that a 90% improvement..the code is very simple: `m <- speedglm(y ~ s1 + s2,data=df)`. Just don't forget to install and call the package. Another issue: you can't use all variables with "." the speedglm does not recognize the dot as "all variables".

Answer (score 8):

Other usefull packages are:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/gputools.pdf
with **gpuGlm**
and
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/mgcv.pdf
see mgcv.parallel section about 
`gam(..., control=list(nthreads=nc))`
or 
`bam(..., cluster=makeCluster(nc))`
where *nc* is the number of your real cores

Comment: NOTE: `gputools` was "archived on 2017-12-19 as check problems were not corrected despite reminders" (per the CRAN page).

Answer (score 4):

A new options, is my package `parglm`. You can find a comparisons of computation times [here](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/boennecd/parglm/blob/master/vignettes/parglm.html). A plot of the computation time versus number of used cores on a 18 core machine in the vignette for two of the implemented methods is given below

[image]

The dashed line is the computation time from `glm` and the dotted line is the computation time from `speedglm`. The method with the open circles compute the Fisher information and then solves the normal equation as in `speedglm`. The full circles makes a QR decomposition as `glm`. The former is faster but less stable.

I have added some more comments on the QR method in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53355094/5861244) on a related question.